How to correct fake device specifications?
I bought two Android tablets which supposedly came with Android 12, 16GB of memory, and 1TB of storage. Unfortunately, when I started adding apps and videos, it soon ran out of space.
I followed a solution on the forum, installed F-Droid, Termux, and ran it, which informed me that the tablets are Android 8, 16GB RAM, and 32GB of storage.
Is there any way I can de-fake them and show the correct attributes?

IMHO it's not about proving anything, they'll ignore you. It's a way to do business in some certain places. That's why I buy here in Europe with a real 2 year warranty and waste no time on those "marketplaces".

Yes I agree, I won't get stung again, and to use the tablets I would like them to show the correct specification. So if any one knows how I can de-fake them i.e. put them to their true settings I would be grateful

The fake is usually hard coded in some system apps. Also some system functions may return fake data (to hide the real data from system info apps). Or alternatively I have read that some faked ROMs simply manipulate the system info apps. In conclusion the fake data is create by some modifications to the used ROM e.g. manipulate shown text in RAM. So you would need an original ROM without those modifications. But that will be hard to get as you don't know the real manufacturer and model name.

@ColinEvans Having a correct specifications could be meaningful target, depends on your case. No practical experience here, but from some tech articles I read in past, often another app for HW info shows a real information, because they only hardcodednthose data into the system information app. In other times it's more complicated, it could even be that the HW itself (i.e. memory chip) provides purposely wrong designation and information. I'd say google an app they use in this case and try to use it and if it doesn't work, have a think if it's worth your time to go into some time sinkhole.
